# Is a quadratic differential literally a square of a differential?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

I have seen definitions of quadratic differentials as functions $\omega : TS \to \mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $\omega(\lambda v) = \lambda^2 \omega(v)$, and that we can write them as $\omega = f_i dz_i^2$ where $f_i = f_j \left(\frac{dz_i}{dz_j}\right)^2$. Does that mean that the $dz^2$ is literally the square of $dz$? I.e. that for a point $p \in S$ and $v \in T_pS$ that $(dz^2)|_p(v) = (dz|_p(v))^2$? As such, those quadratic differentials would satisfy the square of the scalar multiple thing, along with $$dz^2(v + w) = dz^2(v) + 2 dz(v) dz(w) + dz^2(w).$$

Comment: It really depend on how you define the square of $dz$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quadratic differential may be viewed as a symmetric two-form,
$\phi_z(u,v)=a(z) dz(u)dz(v)$
(a bit like a Riemannian metric). The point is that it takes values in ${\Bbb C}$ and that it is possible to multiply complex numbers (no complex conjugation). So your two last formulae are correct. You could e.g. equally well write the last as:
$$ \phi(v+w,v+w)=\phi(v,v)+2\phi(v,w)+\phi(w,w)$$ in terms of the two form.

Later edit: The formula mixing $f_i$ and $f_j$ is also fine when interpreting $z_i(z_j)$ as a change of coordinate charts.

Comment: If $\phi_\alpha : U_\alpha \to \mathbb{C}$ are the chart maps, and $z \in U_i \cap U_j$ then $$dz_i/dz_j(z) = (\phi_i \circ \phi_j^{-1})^\prime(\phi_j(z)).$$  The relationship between $f_i$ and $f_j$ is just change of coordinates.

Thanks for your comment, it cleared things up for me. :))

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were in a higher dimensional space. Indeed for the change of coordinates you are perfectly right!

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: Can you please recommend me a good reference for quadratic differentials in complex analysis? I heard that it is very useful and interesting area. I like to study it by myself. Thank you.

Comment: @Nil The classical book http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540130352 of K Strebel is very good, though a bit difficult. Unfortunately I don't know of a good introductory book on the subject.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: Thank you for your help. I found few chapters of the book that you mentioned. However it is not easy to understand as I know nothing about Riemann surfaces.